# Activity Reload every time

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-listview, activity-lifecycle

I have an Activity with a ListView (ItemsActivity) which its contents come from a JSON API. When I press in one item in the ListView it loads another Activity with the details information (DetailActivity) . The problem is, when I press the Back Button, ItemsActivity reload the ListView again.

I don't know where I can find more information about this. I came from iOS where the previous screen is not reload every time.

I want to keep the ListView data between activities. I tested to call loadListItems() method from onResume() but same result.

Here is and brief sample of my code. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciated.

```
/* ItemsActivity.java */
public class ItemsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private ListView listItemView;
  private Movie[] movies;
  private ProgressBar progressBar;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler);

    listItemView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listItemView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    loadListItems();
  }

  private void loadListItems(){
    // Http call
    ...
    // Iterate JSON and saving to movies array
    ...
    progressBar.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);

    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(ItemsActivity.this, movies);
     listItemView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  /* Adapter Class */

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("item_id", 1);
    startActivity(i);
  }
}
```

I just tested with a new Project with 2 Activities, ActivityOne and ActivityTwo. ActivityOne have a button, when a pressed its load ActivityTwo and when I press the back button, in ActivityOne the method onCreate() is called again.

Comment: Can you try putting a log in onCreate() and one in onResume() to see if it's indeed being called every time?

Comment: Can you post your second activity code? I think you're starting again ActivityOne and not jsut finishing the ActivityTwo. Because onCreate() shouldn't be called when you come back from ActivityTwo.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that "I tested to call loadListItems() method from onResume() but same result." This onResume() code is culprit.

OnResume() will get called whenever your activity gets focus again. If you are calling loadListItems() in onResume() then it will get called everytime you come back from your second activity to this activity.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()

Comment: Currently I'm calling loadListItems() only in onCreate() not in onResume().

Comment: I hope you are not relaunching ItemsActivity  when you press back button from DetailActivity()....

Comment: How can I now that ? DetailActivity does not have any code relating to ItemsActivity.

Comment: hmm...in this case please add logs in onCreate() and onResume() and check. You can also put new exception().printStackTrace() in loadListItems() function so that you will now its stackTrace and who is calling it. It will be helpful to you for backtracking issue.

Comment: I just tested with a new Project with 2 Activities, ActivityOne and ActivityTwo. 

ActivityOne have a button, when a pressed its load ActivityTwo and when I press the back button, in ActivityOne the method onCreate() is called again.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use StartActivityForResult and not StartActivity.  Then in the second activity, override the onBackPressed method and finish() the second activity within this method. Override the onActivityResult method in your first activity and this activity will be called and not the onCreate method and the ListView will not be reloaded.

Comment: **That's wrong!!!** using `StartActivityForResult` instead of `StartActivity` has nothing to do with Activity's lifecycle. `StartActivityForResult` is used if you're waiting for callbacks from the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was only when I pressed the back button from Action Bar and I fix it with onOptionsItemSelected method.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```